# How to use addView to add CustomView?

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

I use below code in main.java, it is work!

```
FrameLayout view = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);
TextView product = new TextView(this);
product.setText("Product");
view.addView(product);
```

But I want to add CustomView, it is not work

```
FrameLayout view = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);
CustomView v = new CustomView(this); //can't create new object
v.setImageResource(R.mipmap.scale);
view.addView(v);
```

How can I add CustomView by addView?
Thanks

The CustomView Class

```
public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public CustomView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
    init();
}
```

attrs.xml

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CustomView">
        <attr name="src" format="reference" />           
        <attr name="editable" format="boolean"/>         
        <attr name="frameColor" format="color" />         
        <attr name="frameWidth" format="dimension" />    
        <attr name="framePadding" format="dimension" />  
        <attr name="degree" format="float" />           
        <attr name="scale" format="float" />              
        <attr name="controlDrawable" format="reference"/>
        <attr name="controlLocation">                    
            <enum name="left_top" value="0" />
            <enum name="right_top" value="1" />
            <enum name="right_bottom" value="2" />
            <enum name="left_bottom" value="3" />
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Error log:

```
03-20 23:26:11.278: E/AndroidRuntime(6706): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.smallmouth./com.smallmouth..PhotoEdit}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are extending View class (or some child of view class) right? If yes, you need to call the super method and pass the context to the parent in constructor which you're not doing. The current version would be like this

```
public class CustomView extends View {

public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}
}
```

BTW you only need first constructor in your case